# Office mobile scripting

Tags: windows-phone-7

I’d like to create a script which automatically pins an Office Mobile bookmarked location.  This would require bookmarking a specific URL within the Office Mobile app, and then pinning the location as a tile.

Can anyone comment on whether or not this is possible, and if there’s dev documentation on this topic?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can pin other applications, but perhaps you could create a secondary tile of your application using ShellTile and have it open a URL pointing at the document you want pinned.

Comment: Thank you - looks like I'll need to read into this a bit.  I don't quite follow on how I could have a OfficeHub tile point to a URL, but my dev experience is limited so I will look into that as well.  Appreciate your help.